# Validation failed if the Compare happened between Integer

Tags: citrus-framework

I have  to test one Temp Sensitive IoT device API, Where Need to pass the Maximum and Minimum Temp in the Request Paylod, And the Response need to validate if the correct data is processed successfully. I have used the method **.validate** **.validate("$.minVal", "(${minVal})")** **minVal = 20** to do a validation. But however the script is ended up with the exception as follow

> FAILURE: Caused by: ValidationException: Validation failed: Values not
>    equal for element '$.maxVal', expected '(20.0)' but was '20

Request--> {"minVal": "20.0", "maxVal": "20.0"}

Response--> {"maxVal":20,"minVal":20,}

Note: if my Request Input is 20.12 its working fine.

Appreciate you guys help.

Comment: Hi All, Can anyone Help me Here, Not able to find a clue why its failing

Comment: Issue Resolved, Passed the Wrong data in .validate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all remove the brackets `()` around `${minVal}` variable. Secondly your `minVal` variable value is obviously a decimal number `20.0`. The received value in Json is a non-decimal number `20`. This is why the validation did fail - I think the error message is pretty clear.